# Strong tag in XML to XSLT transofrmation

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have an XML like this:

```
<texto>
    <mytag>
        <es><strong>a very important text</strong> and other text</es>
    <mytag>
</texto>
```

I apply an XSLT transformation to obtain an HTML file, but the resulting HTML is not labeled `<strong>` that I put in the XML. The text "a very important text" appears correctly, but it is not wrapped by the tag `<strong>`.

Why?

How I can do to make the label appear `<strong>` reach the resulting HTML file?.

Comment: maybe you should show us your xslt transformation...

Comment: The question is incomplete without posting XSLT code!

Comment: Sounds like you've used `<xsl:value-of>` somewhere that needs either `copy-of` or `apply-templates` instead, but it's impossible to be more specific without seeing the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the XSLT that does work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//es"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="es">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|text()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<texto>
    <mytag>
        <es><strong>a very important text</strong> and other text</es>
    </mytag>
</texto>
```

Output file:

```
<strong>a very important text</strong> and other text
```